# Hide the validation output mark (✘) symbol hide when page is loaded/reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the code below with HTML5 pattern matching on the input boxes and the CSS3 `:invalid` and `:valid` pseudo-selectors to display the output of the validation (valid value or not) in the `div.input-validation` available next to the input box. This works as expected but it displays the validation mark (✘ - invalid input) during page load itself and on re-loading the page. How should I avoid this?

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  input {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .3em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: .2em;
  } 
  input[type="text"]:valid {
    color: green;
  }
  input[type="text"]:valid ~ .input-validation::before {
    content: "\2714";
    color: green;
  }
  input[type="text"]:invalid ~ .input-validation::before {
    content: "\2718";
    color: red;
  }
  .input-validation {
    display: inline-block;
  } 
</style>
<?echo $passwordregister;?>
<input name="pw" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="pw" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,22}" autofocus required >
<div class="input-validation"></div>
```

Comment: not able to understand your question.... Please try to elaborate...

Comment: It's hard to understand what you need. couple of suggestions: create a live demo in jsfiddle.com and try to explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: What did you try? At least show your effort, don't just ask how to do stuff.

Comment: I feel the question was a reasonably good one but had not received enough attention because the problem description was pretty minimal and vague. So, I have modified the title and description to better explain the problem (as per my understanding of it). Please feel free to modify if you feel the description is incorrect mate.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the invalid value (✘) symbol on page load using either one of the following options.

**Option 1:** Hide the `span` which contains the symbol on page load and display it only when some `keypress` event has happened on the input text box.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].onkeypress = showSymbol;
  }

  function showSymbol() {
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "inline-block"; // display the span next to the input in which key was pressed.
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: .3em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: .2em;
}
input[type="text"]:valid {
  color: green;
}
input[type="text"]:valid + .input-validation::before {
  content: "\2714";
  color: green;
}
input[type="text"]:invalid + .input-validation::before {
  content: "\2718";
  color: red;
}
.input-validation {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="pw" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="pw" class="new" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,22}" autofocus required/> <span class="input-validation"></span>
```

---

**Option 2:** Define the CSS rules based on the presence of certain class (say `visited`) and assign this class only when some key is pressed in the input box.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].onkeypress = showSymbol;
  }

  function showSymbol() {
    this.classList.add("visited"); // add the visited class
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: .3em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: .2em;
}
input[type="text"].visited:valid {
  color: green;
}
input[type="text"].visited:valid + .input-validation::before {
  content: "\2714";
  color: green;
}
input[type="text"].visited:invalid + .input-validation::before {
  content: "\2718";
  color: red;
}
.input-validation {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input name="pw" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="pw" class="new" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,22}" autofocus required/> <span class="input-validation"></span>
```

**Note:**

- I have replaced the `~` in your CSS selectors with `+` because `~` selects all siblings which match the selector whereas the `+` selects only the adjacent sibling. Using `~` would make the `span` next to all input boxes get displayed (when you have multiple input boxes in the form) as soon as you type a value in the first.
- I have also modified the `.input-validation` from `div` to `span` but that is more of a personal preference and you can just retain the original `div` itself without any difference in functionality.

Comment: how script how a look?